# Dynamic title in React Native Elements Header component

Tags: react-native, header, react-native-elements

I am using https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/header

Also I am using react native tabs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

```
    <Drawer
    ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
    type="overlay"
    content={< MyDrawer />}
    tapToClose={true}
    open={false}
    openDrawerOffset={0.5}
    captureGestures={true}
    styles={drawerStyles}
    // tweenHandler={Drawer.tweenPresets.parallax}
    tweenHandler={(ratio) => {
      return {
        mainOverlay: { opacity: ratio / 1.5, backgroundColor: 'black' }
      }
    }}
    panOpenMask={0.1} >
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Header
        leftComponent={
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.calendarClick()}>
              <Ionicons name="calendar-outline" size={24} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        }
        centerComponent={{ text: "DYNAMIC_TITLE_HERE", style: { color: '#000', fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 18, marginTop: 3 } }}
        rightComponent={<Ionicons name="cloud-upload-outline" size={24} />}
      />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName = "ion-md-help";

              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused
                  ? 'ios-information-circle'
                  : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
              }

              // You can return any component that you like here!
              return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
          })}
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#2B95DA',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          }}>

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Targets"
            component={TargetsScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name="rocket" color={color} size={24} />
            }}
          />

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Settings"
            component={SettingsScreen}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <Ionicons name="settings" color={color} size={24} />,
            }} />

        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  </Drawer >
```

I didn't find any possibility how can I dynamically replace DYNAMIC_TITLE_HERE in ->centerComponent. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're passing your dynamic title to your screen when you navigate to it.

Then you can pass the route obj to your header and get the title from route.params